# Delete messages after 300th record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table `groupMessage` is used for record group user Messages

Table `groupMessageNum` is used for record whose number of messages is more than 300.

```
 -------------------
 | groupMessage    |
 |-----------------|
 |     id          |
 |    hostId       |
 |    roomId       |
 ===================


 ---------------------
 | groupMessageNum   |
 |-------------------|
 |     id            |
 |    hostId         |
 |    roomId         |
 =====================
```

I am trying to delete the records in `groupMessage` that are in `groupMessageNum` and also delete the records in `groupMessageNum`.

If the number of the records in `groupMessage` to be deleted is more than 300, I will delete the records after 300th record.

my sql is :

```
delete group, groupNum from groupMessage group, groupMessageNum
groupNum where group.hostId = groupNum.hostId and group.roomId =
groupNum.roomId;
```

This will delete all the record in groupMessage.

So, how can I only delete the records after 300th?

Example:

There are 100 users and 60 users have more than 300 messages. All the user messages are in the groupMessage table. 60 user`s ids are in the groupMessageNum for their messages are more than 300.

Now i am trying to delete the use`s message which is after 300th message. So I firstly find the userid in the groupMessageNum table and then delete those messages in the groupMessage table.

Comment: Try the `limit` option on delete queries? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: I know limit but I don`t know how to add it into sql ): @MarcB

Comment: I will delete Records from two table not the only groupMessage@MarcB

Comment: @Felix please give us an example

Comment: @nos sorry I leave out this. there is a field msgTime. sorry

Comment: I have updated my post with field `msgTime` have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DELETE group, groupNum
FROM groupMessage group
     INNER JOIN (SELECT hostId 
                 FROM group 
                 ORDER BY msgTime ASC 
                 LIMIT 300, 9999999999
                ) group2
         ON group.hostId = group2.hostId
     INNER JOIN groupMessageNum groupNum
         ON group.hostId = groupNum.hostId AND
            group.roomId = groupNum.roomId;
```

or another way you may try this:

```
DELETE group, groupNum
FROM groupMessage group
     INNER JOIN (SELECT hostId, (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank
                 FROM group, (SELECT @rank:= 0) a
                 ORDER BY msgTime ASC 
                ) group2
         ON group.hostId = group2.hostId AND
            rank > 300
     INNER JOIN groupMessageNum groupNum
         ON group.hostId = groupNum.hostId AND
            group.roomId = groupNum.roomId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE A, B
FROM groupMessage A
INNER JOIN groupMessageNum B on A.hostId = B.hostId and A.roomId=B.roomId
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM groupMessage LIMIT 300,999999) C
ON A.id = B.id
```

Comment: This may not work always... because sometimes even if group.id=300 may not be 300th record